# Adding the values of the points in a dotchart

Tags: r, plot

I can draw a dotchart with the following code:

```
library("Hmisc")
df <- data.frame(ID=c("a","b","c","d","e"),a=c(1:5),b=c(2:6))
dotchart3(as.matrix(df[,c(2,3)]),df[,c(1)],pch=c(1,2))
```

But how can I add the numerical values of the points just above or below the dots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `text`, which takes an x position as its first argument, a y position as its second argument, and the label value as its third argument. These are vectorized, so you can just pass columns of your data.frame. The `pos` argument specifies labels below the specified points (1):

```
text(df[,2], df[,1], df[,2], pos = 1)
text(df[,3], df[,1], df[,3], pos = 1)
```

or above the specified points (3):

```
text(df[,2], df[,1], df[,2], pos = 3)
text(df[,3], df[,1], df[,3], pos = 3)
```

Here's an example of the latter configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
 library("Hmisc")
 df <- data.frame(ID=c("a","b","c","d","e"),a=c(1:5),b=c(2:6))
 dotchart3(as.matrix(df[,c(2,3)]),df[,c(1)],pch=c(1,2))

 #a function where the two first input are identical to dotchart3

 addVal = function(x,labels,
                   decimals=0,
                   cex=0.1,
                   x.offset=0,
                   y.offset=.2) {
   len=length(labels)
   for(j in 1:dim(x)[2]) text(x = x[,j]+x.offset,
                              y = (1:len)+y.offset,
                              lab = paste("val=",round(x[,j],decimals)),
                              cex=cex)
 }

 addVal(df[,2:3],df[,1],cex=.7)
```